# What Views Are Auto Saved on a Configuration Change

Tags: android

On a configuration change, such as Screen Orientation Change, Android will automatically save some view information. For example, any text entered into an EditText will be saved and re-entered after the application is restarted. However, a TextView's text is not saved.

Does anyone have a list of Views that have data saved? And which values of each View?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The framework saves the state of Views whose state can be changed directly by the user: ListView (for selection for instance), EditText, etc.

Comment: That's a great answer! I never thought about it in that way. Thanks!